# Calcular data da coluna - 6 meses da data atual (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho uma coluna no db que é `D_EMISSAO` e nela tem uma data `yyyyddmm`.

Tenho que mostrar os dados que estão relacionados a coluna `D_EMISSAO` se não ultrapassar 6 meses de acordo com a data `D_EMISSAO` com a data atual.

Tentei fazer de diversas formas, mas nada saiu. Tem como me ajudarem?

Comment: Qual é o tipo de dados do campo D_EMISSAO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
    CAMPO1, CAMPO2
FROM 
    TABELA 
WHERE 
    CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,DATEDIFF(DD,0,D_EMISSAO)) >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,DATEDIFF(DD,0,GETDATE())))
```

Dessa forma, está sendo desconsiderada a hora que é retornada no `GETDATE()` e que pode estar sendo gravada no seu campo.

Answer (score 2):

Se for para não ultrapassar os últimos 6 meses, tente isso:

`SELECT * FROM <TABELA> WHERE D_EMISSAO >= dateadd(month, -6, getdate())`